# Weblogic Managed Servers Restart On Own

Tags: weblogic, cluster-computing, weblogic8.x

We are running WebLogic 8.1.6.0 and when we attempt to shutdown all managed servers in a cluster some of the managed servers shutdown and start back up prior to us interacting with them. In order to stop all of the managed servers we have to manual force shutdown each server that “restarts” it’s self and often the manually process must be preformed several times. Has anyone else experienced this issue or similar issues with controlling managed servers in a Weblogic cluster?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you configured the servers to use NodeManager in WL 8.1?

By default, Node Manager automatically restarts Managed Servers that crash, and Managed Servers that Node Manager killed because their health state was "failed".

Comment: So in Server Console, if I click on Servers -> the tab labeled "Configuration"-> the tab labeled "Health Monitoring" I noticed that "Auto Restart" is checked. Are you saying that this option may be causing the issue ? BTW: Thanks for the post : )

Comment: yes it is via AutoRestart.
look at http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E11035_01/wls100/server_start/nodemgr.html#wp1081879

Comment: The behavior continues with or without the Auto Restart checked.

Comment: Do you want to try uncheck for Admin Server as well - and all Managed and then restart all servers.